# c++ iteration exception over int array

Tags: c++

why does the code cause exception ?

exception: Access violation writing location 0x000001A88BF5D000.

```
int* ints = new int(1000000);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    ints[i] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Don't use raw array allocation in c++. Better use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead. Usage of `new` / `delete` manually is just error prone, and should be left for least resort in cases of advanced problems (and advanced programmers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allocating a single integer. If you want to allocate an integer array, you should use square brackets.

```
int* ints = new int[1000000]();
```

Comment: ... and delete the array subsequently with `delete []`.